# After pseudo-element not showing box-shadow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a metro-like menu, and when user hovers over each tile I want it to show a box-shadow. Now I got it to work, but I read that its better to use it on `::after` pseudo-element to be more smooth, but it does not seem to work. Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fk8e0Let/).

```css
p.tile {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5rem;
  background: #58588E;
  color: white;
  margin: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
p.tile::after {
  content: "";
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 20px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
p.tile:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="tile-link">
  <p class="tile">My Progress</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the `::after` pseudo element doesn't actually have any width or height. You can set `position:relative` on the container, and set `position:absolute` + `left:0`, `right:0`, `top:0`, `bottom:0` tricks to make it the same size as the container.

```css
p.tile {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5rem;
  background: #58588E;
  color: white;
  margin: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* new */
  position: relative;
}
p.tile::after {
  content: "";
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 20px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  /* new */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
p.tile:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="tile-link">
  <p class="tile">My Progress</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created the pseudo-element but you haven't give it any height or width. First of all you have to give it display.

```
p.tile {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5rem;
    background: #58588E;
    color: white;
    margin: 2rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}
p.tile::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 20px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
p.tile:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```